# Pull SAP data into salesforce using Cast Iron Adaptor

Tags: integration

Is it possible that salesforce will pull data  without importing data from SAP?
I have read some articles that there is no way that salesforce will pull data other than webservices.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Do you already have Cast Iron available/purchased and you're looking for information about how the integration technology works?

Comment: Not yet but we are planning to purchase it thats why we are currently researching.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of options that you have:

1. Use any Cloud ETL tool like [Informatica Cloud](https://www.informatica.com/cloud.html#fbid=DtPVeOhDbuD), [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/) and few others out there
2. You can have automate scripts put the data from SAP in a CSV in a sftp or ftp, and you can use any data loader (like [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/) ) to push that data into SFDC. If you do not have any transformation in between, Couple of these tools can be free.
3. Use a free tool like Talend Open Studio, It's a free enterprise quality tool (most part of it is free). It's a on prem tool, so you may have to consider your IT strategy before you choose any on prem tool (as you may already know :-) ).

Trigger points:

1. You can make a call-out from SFDC using workflow to initiate the integration from salesforce
2. You can invoke integration from SAP:

a. [Web Service Invocation from JCo server](http://searchsap.techtarget.com/answer/How-to-invoke-a-Web-service-from-SAP-using-a-JCo-server), 
b. [Invoke External Web Services via Coding](http://scn.sap.com/community/business-bydesign/studio/blog/2014/01/14/video-how-to-invoke-an-external-web-service-via-coding), 
c. [Via Cloud Application Studio](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3726623) and etc

Comment: Hi @srinivas, if Salesforce will pull data from SAP will it consume API calls?

Comment: It depends on how you are pulling the data.  So any action that sends a call to API counts except - a. Outbound messages, b. Apex callouts.  You can find a good article on salesforce help docs - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/implementation_considerations.htm#topic-title_request_metering

Answer (score 1):

For getting data into salesforce you will always have to trigger an import at some point. 
There are several tools available for importing data.

- You can use integration tools like action, cast iron, informatica, ...
- You can use tools like dataloader or jitterbit.

Next to that you can also use a feature called salesforce connect.

> Salesforce Connect provides seamless integration of data across system
>   boundaries by letting your users view, search, and modify data that’s
>   stored outside your Salesforce org.

See: [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_about.htm)

Comment: for cast iron integration, do i need to create a class to pull data from SAP?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SAP or Cast-iron, but as far as I know the tool offers a built in connector that can pull data from SAP and push that to Salesforce. I expect that outside from creating an interface in cast iron you will not have much additional work.